# Redirect back to origin page after using get_delete_post_link()

Tags: hooks, front-end, actions, customization

I need to implement frontend and backend redirection after delete specific post using get_delete_post_link(). Which hook i can use? Any advice would be appreciated.

Something similar to :

```
<?php echo wp_login_url( $redirect ); ?>
```

I need to redirect to front-end page after post deleted, similar to wp_login_url can do.

As Barry said my code might look like below:

```
add_filter( 'get_delete_post_link', 'some_function', 20 );
function some_function() {
  wp_redirect( get_permalink() );
  exit;
}
```

Assume get_permalink will get current page where get_delete_post_link called.
Any better way for this?

Answer (score 0):

Theres a filter you can hook on to.

```
apply_filters( 'get_delete_post_link', wp_nonce_url( $delete_link, "$action-{$post->post_type}_{$post->ID}" ), $post->ID, $force_delete );
```

Check the raw function here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L954

Can't advise much else without seeing your code.

Edit:

its nasty buy you can do

```
add_filter( 'get_delete_post_link', 'some_function', 20 );
function some_function() {
  wp_redirect( home_url('/') );
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Wheres the rest of the code that includes your call to get_delete_post_link